# how to iterate through website scrapy

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

To give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve; I'm trying to build an article scraper for my website, I'm wanting to iterate through links on all of my webpages, pull out the metadata to determine if it's an article, if it is, store that URL + associated data in a database (Mongo).

I've found a [python-goose article extractor](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose) which I'd like to use to the retrieve the full article. But I think I'm getting ahead of myself there.

The code below is my attempt, it works, but doesn't iterate. I assume I need a for loop in there but I don't know how to go about it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from harland.items import *

class StuffSpider(Spider):
    name = "stuff"
    allowed_domains = ["stuff.co.nz"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.stuff.co.nz/business/industries/70284251/brazil-a-surprise-growth-market-for-moa"
    ]
    rules = (Rule(sle(allow=["/business/"]), callback='parse_item', follow=True)


    def parse(self, response):

        article = Selector(response)
        page = Selector(response).xpath('/html/head/meta[9]')
        page_type = page.xpath('//meta[@property="og:type"]/@content').extract()

        if "article" in page_type:
          item = StuffItem()

          item['url'] = page.xpath('//meta[@property="og:url"]/@content')
          item['title'] = page.xpath('//meta[@property="og:title"]/@content')
          item['description'] = page.xpath('//meta[@property="og:description"]/@content')
          yield item
          yield Request(item['url'], callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not use loops or any `Rule` your code won't iterate.

Because of your `example.com` domain it is hard to tell how is the best to go through the articles (and for now I won't bring Goose into the answer).

You could set up a `Rule` which extracts and follows URLs on the site. You can use this approach to walk through the site and visit all URLs (you can define restrictions too) and execute specific crawling behaviour. See [the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) for more info.

The second approach is to extract the URLs by yourself and `yield` it as a new `Request` to let Scrapy know which site to visit. This has a bit more coding overhead but less network traffic because you tell which sites to load. To read more about `Request` look at [the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects).

And if you extract a list of URLs or sub-trees from the site being parsed use a loop (most of the time a `for` would be ok) to have your iteration.

**Update based on the comments and edits**

Your extraction cannot work in the `parse` method because you are trying to set `Selector` objects as `Field` values and then use one such `Selector` as the URL of the `Request`. You should `extract` the content from those selectors.

Your `Rule` defines a `callback='parse_item'`. Currently I do not see the implementation of the `parse_item` function. So even if the `Rule` hits you get no results because of the missing `callback`.

So to solve the issue with the `parse` function use the following to fill your `item`:

```
item['url'] = page.xpath('//meta[@property="og:url"]/@content').extract()[0]
item['title'] = page.xpath('//meta[@property="og:title"]/@content').extract()
item['description'] = page.xpath('//meta[@property="og:description"]/@content').extract()
```

This should enable your `Request` to fire up and call again the `parse` method -- which would result in some duplication and Scrapy would tell it to you with a `DEBUG` message.

Comment: Hi GHajba, thanks for taking the time to reply, I've included domains to assist with helping and I've also updated my little to do a callback (which didn't work and a rule, which also didn't work :( Can you please take a look? Thank you.